# How to select a particular value from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

How can I  select a particular value from a DataFrame based on values in some column in Pandas?
I cannot use index as my data has no pandas indices

In SQL, I would use:

```
SELECT name 
FROM contacts
WHERE phone = '234-567-8900'
```

I want to return the name of the contact with the phone number given.

I tried to look at Pandas' documentation, but I did not immediately find the answer.

The closest I got was:

```
contact.loc[contact['Phone']=='234-567-8900', 'name']
```

but this returns a dtype: object and I just want the string value of the name

Comment: `contacts.loc[contact['Phone']=='234-567-8900', 'name'].tolist()`, in fact str in dataframe will be shown as object dtype.

Comment: This got me really close actually. It returned an array with just the string of the name inside. I added a '[0]' at the end of your code, and got the string itself, but is there a cleaner/easier way?

Answer (score 0):

```
contacts[(contacts['Phone'] == '234-567-8900')]['name'].iloc[x]
```

x is any integer - if there's only one element then set x to 0

You first select all rows where contacts is 234-567-8900, and then for those rows, you take the name column

Comment: Just tried- Still returns a dtype object. How do I get the value inside?

Comment: I just edited my answer - it depends on the number of elements returned by the filter - you can loop through using a for loop if you want